# Help understanding a $3n+1$ problem programming project

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

I was going through [this website](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36) where I found `3n + 1` problem.

I was not able to understand what the `output` should be.

I understood if the input is `1 and 10`
then the numbers between 1 to 10 need to be in consideration, and the `output` will be `20`.
But I am wondering how it can be `20`.

Where as 10 -  10 5  16  8  4  2  1. (Total 6 excluding 16).
Then how can be it `20`?

Please could you please help me.

Please make me understand the problem, What it really wants me to solve?

Please tell me if I had put some wrong tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the input is $i=1$ and $j=10$ then you need to consider the full cycle for each starting value $i=1\le n \le 10=j$, consider all of their "cycle lengths" and return the largest cycle length.

For $n=10$ the cycle length is 7, since you need to include 16.

Given $i=1,j=10$ as input, the cycle length for $n=1$ is $1$, for $n=2$ is 2, for $n=3$ is $8$, and for $n=4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ is respectively $3,6,9,17,4,20,7$. The largest value in this range is 20, which should be your answer.

Similarly, if $i=100,j=200$, then the longest cycle length is $125$ which you find starting with $n=171$ then considering the full cycle $C=\{171,514,257,772,\ldots,4,2,1\},\vert C\vert=125$.

Comment: There's some confusing nonstandard terminology involved here. It looks like the exercise is  asking for the length of the sequence from the starting number to the first 1. But that sequence is not a "cycle" -- the only known cycle is $1\mapsto 4\mapsto 2\mapsto 1$ of length 3.

Comment: @Zander: Thanks a lot, for making me understand...